# Efficient half-angle formula for both sine and cosine when both are available

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Given a unit vector $\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta\\\sin\theta\end{bmatrix}$ I seek to efficiently find any vector parallel (or anti-parallel) to $\begin{bmatrix}\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}\\\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\end{bmatrix}$.

One way could be to use the [half-angle identities](https://www.cuemath.com/half-angle-formula/) to calculate the components of the new vector. However this would require calculating two square roots.

An alternative I considered is to simply add $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ to the original vector $\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta\\\sin\theta\end{bmatrix}$. While this is efficient and works in almost all cases, it runs into numerical problems when $\theta$ is equal to or near to $\pi$.

When both $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ are available, is there an identity that could efficiently provide the required vector (e.g. by calculating only one square root)?

Comment: Having calculated either $\cos(\theta/2)$ or $\sin(\theta/2),$ wouldn't it be OK to calculate the other by division, using $\sin\theta = 2\sin(\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2)$?

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Nice, but I suppose that would need branching to avoid risk of near-zero divisor.

Comment: Very importantly, what is the range for your $\theta$? I think I have a work around, but it only works if you are only considering angles in $(0,\pi)$ or $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, because what are you considering a valid half angle for something say $120^\circ$? Is it $60^\circ$ or $120^\circ + 180^\circ /2 = 150^\circ$? Those two angles are half angles of something anti/parallel to the original, but are not anti/parallel to each other.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Valid half-angle for 120 degrees is 60 degrees. The resulting vector is valid if it points at 60 degrees (parallel) or at 60+180 degrees (anti-parallel).

Comment: Are you saying your range then is $(0,\pi)$ for your angles?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Essentially we are interested in finding the line through the origin that bisects the sector (top or bottom sector, same bisector). The input unit vector could lie anywhere on the unit circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the tangent half angle identities from your link

$$\tan\frac{\theta}{2} = \cdots = \frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta} = \frac{1-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$$

The first equivalence yields your formula

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\\ \sin\frac{\theta}{2}\end{pmatrix} \sim \begin{pmatrix}1+\cos\theta\\ \sin\theta\end{pmatrix}$$

and the second yields a formula that will respond numerically better around $\pi$

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\\ \sin\frac{\theta}{2}\end{pmatrix} \sim \begin{pmatrix}\sin\theta \\ 1-\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$

I would have cases in your code that chooses which formula to use depending on whether the $x$ component of the vector is positive or negative.